# Echo Checkbox php in table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have a mysql database , i'm able to select the information from the tables and i'm able to echo the values in a table but i'm not able to add a checkbox under the status column . The error is : unexpected checkbox.

```
<?php
ini_set('date.timezone','Asia/Beirut');
$time = date('H:i', time());

if(isset($_SESSION["Id"])){
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'projetphp');
    $results = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM user,user_has_class,class WHERE user.Id= user_has_class.User_Id AND class.Id= user_has_class.Class_Id AND class.Id = '.$_SESSION['Id'].' ;');

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);


    while( $row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['FirstName']."</td><td>".$row['LastName']."</td><td><input type="checkbox" value=""/></td><tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

[image: I want the checkbox under status. This is the site so far]

Comment: You are using double quotes inside double quotes. Either enclose the text in single quotes or put html entities for them.

Comment: Also check the answer below regarding the mistake in the closing tag <tr>.

Answer (score 0):

1)You code isn't working because you are using `""` within `""` and that is causing string to break:

2) you aren't closing `</tr>` properly instead using `<tr>` to end the tag.

Hence change your echo statement to the following:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['FirstName']."</td><td>".$row['LastName']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' value=''/></td></tr>";
```